# how to open all text files from a directory

Tags: c#, winforms, io

I need peace of code that open all text files from a specific folder and do some process and then save it.
For example theses are my files  in this folder

```
MainFolder=>Subfolder1=>Textfile1.txt  
MainFolder=>Subfolder2=>Textfile1.txt  
MainFolder=>Subfolder2=>Textfile1.txt
```

I don't know how to open all Textfile1 files in the MainFolder folder automatically, and do some process and then save them there.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(MainFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText(file);

    //do processing
    File.WriteAllText(file, text);
}
```